# Изменение файлов приложением AppImage Electron

Tags: linux, electron

Мое приложение записывает и читает информацию из, скажем, data.json, которое необходимо упаковать вместе со всем приложением во время сборки. Я собираю приложение через electron-builder и использую electron-updater, что заставляет меня использовать appimage. Приложение AppImage, скорее всего, записывает файл где-то в /tmp, но при каждом новом запуске он оказывается такой, каким был изначально, т.е стирается. При сборке в .deb такой проблемы не было, но теперь я не могу использовать deb.
В Windows аналогичная проблема, видимо дело в том, что все ресурсы лежат в app.asar, что я могу с этим сделать?